# Specify pixel format for Qt Framebuffer

Tags: qt, embedded, qt5, framebuffer, imx6

I am developing a application on an iMX6UL board using Qt 5.11 and framebuffer platform plugin. The underlying board has connected 16 wires to a 24-bit RGB parallel display, so the output format is RGB565.

Apparently Qt expects RGB24 (...does it?)

The output image of application is corrupted. mostly there is no red, green is yellow and blue is green. Definitely the pixel formats of Qt output on framebuffe and LCD driver does not match. I am wondering if there are any configuration option for Qt platform plugin (either command-line or environment variable) to specify pixel format at runtime...

In case there is no such option at runtime, then how can I compile Qt with specific pixel format and width?

I am looking for some option at runtime like:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='linuxfb:size=800x480,depth=16,format=rgb565'
```

OR (not-very-well-documented) qt compile options like:

```
./configure .... -depth 16 -pixel-format rgb565
```

Comment: What are the outputs of fb-test -f 0 and echo $DISPLAY ?